# INSERT INTO.....SELECT FROM

Tags: php, codeigniter, insert-select

i want to put `calory` as the first value of `fruits`, i couldn't do it, can anyone help?

```
   $sql = 'INSERT INTO fruits VALUES('', ?, ?, ?)'
          SELECT calory
          FROM diet
          WHERE fruit = ?
         ';

   $this->db->query($sql, array($a, $b, $c, $d));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct syntax is :

```
INSERT INTO "table1" ("column1", "column2", ...)
SELECT "column3", "column4", ...
FROM "table2"
```

in your case this should be :

```
INSERT INTO fruits (calory)
SELECT calory
FROM diet
WHERE fruit = ?
```

(if "calory" is the name of the column in the table "fruits")

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix up `INSERT ... SELECT` and `INSERT ... VALUES` in one query. Just select the other values as constants in your `SELECT` statement and you'll be fine:

```
INSERT INTO fruits
  SELECT calory, ?, ?, ?
  FROM diet
  WHERE fruit = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
INSERT INTO fruits SELECT calory, ?, ?, ? FROM diet WHERE fruit = ?
```

should do it...

Answer (score 0):

When you use placeholders for values, (in your case the question marks) you need to use ->prepare() and not ->query(). Also your SQL syntax is completely wrong.
At a guess I think your query should read something like...

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO fruits VALUES('', ?, ?, ?) WHERE fruit = ?"; // Create query string.

$sth = $this->db->prepare($sql); // Prepare the query.
$sth->bindValue(1,$a); // Bind question marks to values
$sth->bindValue(2,$b); // (I am assuming that a,b,c,d are in
$sth->bindValue(3,$c); // the correct order...
$sth->bindValue(4,$d);
$sth->execute(); // Execute the query to insert the data.
```

Answer (score -1):

You mean you need to put the answer of select query into insert query ,please try this

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO fruits VALUES('(SELECT calory
      FROM diet
      WHERE fruit = ?)', ?, ?, ?)'

     ';
```